# Is there any way to test your webapp locally using Opera-Mini (considering that Opera uses a proxy to serve pages to Opera-Mini)

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, opera-mini

How can I test my web app locally using Opera-Mini?

I know that in order to test it using their [Opera-Mini simulator](http://www.opera.com/mobile/demo/) you have to have a public site.  Is it possible to test it out using a local server that is not public to the internet?

The issue stems from the fact that Opera-Mini gets its pages through a proxy server at Opera, and even if you have Opera-Mini installed locally you still can't test out your sites without putting them on the Internet first.  This is the problem I'm trying to get around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, unless you open your site to the internet during test period

Comment: *meh* They need to fix that...I know they have a fix for Opera Mobile...but not Opera-Mini...

Comment: it's not broken, this is by design

Comment: I know that, but this is a problem when you want to privately develop a site that you want to test on Opera-mini (getting the errors out before public deployment).

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure it works fine in Opera Mobile. (Download the Mobile emulator from here - http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/)
2. Understand [OBML](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-binary-markup-language/) to get an idea of what javascript will / won't work.
3. The OBML article is  a little old, so also read the [Web specifications support in Opera products](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/).
4. You can then decide how your web app can degrade gracefully for Opera Mini (if at all it needs to).

Answer (score 1):

Just install [MicroEmulator](http://www.microemu.org/) and inside it Opera Mini, then you can do start it on your local machine.

Comment: Yeah but isn't the problem that when you request a website in Opera-Mini it first has to run it through a proxy server, which requests the site site and then sends it back to Opera-Mini?  

If my site isn't on the public internet during development, it won't be accessible to Opera's proxy server; hence the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngrok(https://ngrok.com/) to securely expose your localhost to an online host that they provide you with. e.g. my-opera-site.ngrok.com